# iOS - autolayout scaling for different screen sizes of buttons over an imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a parent UIView with a UIImageView and another UIView inside. The UIImageView has an image and it's constrained to the same size of the parent UIView. The child UIView is also constrained to the same size of the parent UIView and it has buttons that position above certain parts of the UIImageView (this allows the user to click on the image to trigger an action depending on where the image was clicked).

I've tried to set constraints with AutoLayout by using size classes, but I can't seem to get them to resize accordingly to screen sizes. I've created the fixed constraints on an iPhone 8 screen. iPhone 8, iPhone X, and iPhone 8 Plus all have width Compact/height Regular, however it only looks right on iPhone 8/X. I also would like the button sizes to scale down for iPhone SE/4s.

Here is what it looks like (blue blackground has been replaced for the real image):
[notice the buttons are the same size in all 3 screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9AaM.png)

[parent UIView constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfyVH.png)

[child UIImageView constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8O0B.png)

[child UIView constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N63qc.png)

The buttons inside the child UIView have fixed constraints of top/trailing/leading/bottom according to the iPhone 8/X screen size.

How can I get the buttons to resize accordingly for all screen sizes while maintaining the same position over the image that also scales depending on screen sizes?

**UPDATE:**
After replacing the inner UIView with a StackView and updating the constraints, with the distribution filled equally it looks like the following structure:

[Replaced UIView with StackView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsjmu.png)

How do I get it to look like this?

[original screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzO3L.png)

**UPDATE 2:**

Added spacing and centered X/Y of stackView.

[updated stackView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksKva.png)

**UPDATE 3:** The image I have in the imageView has Content Mode in Aspect Fit. How do I scale the buttons in this mode?

Answer (score 0):

First regarding parent view don't give it static height(371) -> instead give a proportional height constraint to main view

Second regarding inner subviews

1- imageView won't resize as you think as it has leading , Trailing , Top , B constraints

2- same for the view with buttons

instead of give those constraints consider giving centerX&Y with proprtional width & height constraints for these subviews to the parent view

Also stackView will fit for these buttons if you don't already use it

Comment: I don't get what you mean to use the stackView for the buttons. Do I replace the inner UIView with a stackView or do I create stackView inside the UIView?

How does stackView help in resizing? What constraints do I need to set for the stackView?

Comment: I mean you can replace it  as it's perfect in resizing especially giving subviews same size  , you can go  with the UIView if you set the constraints properly but i recommend reading more about it

Comment: If I use a stackView, how do I set the initial constraints of the size and position of the buttons? Do I use leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints for my default view and then stackView will auto adjust accordingly?

Comment: I told you to use centerX,y with pro width& height constraints for the buttons view even if you replaced that view with stackView , the advantage of stackview is that you don't give neither position/size constraints for the subviews as it will stretch automatically when you set **distribution** to fillEqually ,,,,,, your current UI needs nested stackViews vertical/Horizontal ,  don't want to confuse you it's an advanced UI component you can use it when you better understand it's usage

Comment: I've updated everything with what you've said. Now all the buttons are filled equally, but my question from earlier is how do I set the constraints of the buttons for it to look like the original screen? See posted update. Note: all buttons aren't the same size.

Comment: the conntainer stack/view should have width and height which should be proportional so give it centerX,y then control-drag from it to the parent view and select **Equalwidth** then change the multiplier to 0.5 if you want it to fill 0.5 width of any screen size , same logic applies for the height

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work completely because even if I change both height/width multipliers it's still centered to X/Y. I have an image behind which needs to match the position of the buttons. I need spacing between the buttons as well to fit correctly over the image. I can show you a picture of what I'm referring. Is there a way on here to share it privately?

Comment: center the image also with x,y Also there is a spacing property of the stackView to set value between it's subviews

Comment: The image is already centered to x/y with equal width/height to the parent UIView. I've created spacing between both stackViews, but how do I line it up with the image behind? I've posted an update with the actual image this time for clarification. I need to match up the buttons with the white squares behind.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **equal width and equal height constraints** for buttons to make it adopt size according to the screen size.

Place two horizontal views over the image. and make their height constraint equal. for reference view below image.
[image: Equal height for top and bottom views over image]

then place buttons inside those views then set equal width constraints. for reference view below image.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is there a way to not make the buttons equal width? If you see in my image (under updated stackView link), I have 2 buttons that are larger than the other buttons. I also have spacing in between the buttons and the buttons have to stay within black box of the image, they cannot extend to the edges of the View.